# Coding style for the indentation of multi-line IF statement in Visual Basic .NET

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, coding-style, indentation, multiline

If you have a multi-line IF statement, the default indentation can be a bit hard to read:

```
If SomeConditionA _
    AndAlso SomeConditionB _
    AndAlso SomeConditionC Then
    DoSomething()
End If
```

I can think of a few options to solve this, such as:

- indenting the second and third line by 8 instead of 4 spaces,
- not indenting the second and third line at all,
- adding an empty line after the third line,
- ...

But I'd like to know whether there is some *well-established* or even *officially recommended* coding style for this case.

Comment: Update: Apparently Visual Studio 2015 prefers 8 spaces. To test this, type `If SomeConditionA AndAlso` and then hit Enter.

Answer (score 1):

Well actually according to the [coding conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h63fsef3.aspx), you should

> Avoid using the explicit line continuation character "_" in favor of
>   implicit line continuation wherever the language allows it.

So the code should actually look like this:

```
    If SomeconditionA AndAlso
        SomeconditionB AndAlso
        SomeconditionC Then
        DoSomething()
    End If
```

It then states:

> If Pretty listing (reformatting) of code doesn't format continuation
>   lines automatically, manually indent continuation lines one tab stop.
>   However, always left-align items in a list.

So I would say that this is as-per the recommendation (one tab stop indented)